# What is an alternative to using MutablePropertyExtensions.SetValueComparer

Tags: entity-framework

I recently upgraded to .Net 6 and it's seems that Microsoft has removed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MutablePropertyExtensions.SetValueComparer although nothing has been noted in their release notes (So I suspect its something on my end.)

I use that method to serialize an object to JSON and store that in a SQL DB.

```
public class ReportMasterConfigurationReportTemplate : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ReportTemplateHistory>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ReportTemplateHistory> builder)
        {
             builder
             .Property(m => m.Permissions)
             .HasJsonValueConversion();

         }
}
```

The error I receive is:

Void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MutablePropertyExtensions.SetValueComparer(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IMutableProperty, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer)

Has anyone else experienced this while serializing to JSON ?

Comment: any news on this?